Prevent SIGINT propagation from subshell to parent shell in Zsh
I need to prevent SIGINT (Ctrl-C) from propagating from a subshell to its parent shell functions in Zsh.
Here's a minimal example:
function sox-record {
    local output="${1:-$(mktemp).wav}"
    (
        rec "${output}" trim 0 300  # Part of sox package
    )
    echo "${output}"  # Need this to continue executing after Ctrl-C
}

function audio-postprocess {
    local audio="$(sox-record)"
    # Process the audio file...
    echo "${audio}"
}

function audio-transcribe {
    local audio="$(audio-postprocess)"
    # Send to transcription service...
    transcribe_audio "${audio}"  # Never reached if Ctrl-C during recording
}


The current workaround requires trapping SIGINT at every level, which leads to repetitive, error-prone code:
function sox-record {
    local output="${1:-$(mktemp).wav}"
    setopt localtraps
    trap '' INT
    (
        rec "${output}" trim 0 300
    )
    trap - INT
    echo "${output}"
}

function audio-postprocess {
    setopt localtraps
    trap '' INT
    local audio="$(sox-record)"
    trap - INT
    # Process the audio file...
    echo "${audio}"
}

function audio-transcribe {
    setopt localtraps
    trap '' INT
    local audio="$(audio-postprocess)"
    trap - INT
    # Send to transcription service...
    transcribe_audio "${audio}"
}


When the user presses Ctrl-C to stop the recording, I want: 1. The rec subprocess to terminate (working) 2. The parent functions to continue executing (requires trapping SIGINT in every caller)
I know that:

SIGINT is sent to all processes in the foreground process group
Using setsid creates a new process group but prevents signals from reaching the child
Adding trap '' INT in the parent requires all callers to also trap SIGINT to prevent propagationj

Is there a way to isolate SIGINT to just the subshell without requiring signal handling in all parent functions? Or is this fundamentally impossible due to how Unix process groups and signal propagation work?

I took a look at this question, and I tried this:
function sox-record {
    local output="${1:-$(mktemp).wav}"

    zsh -mfc "rec "${output}" trim 0 300" </dev/null >&2 || true

    echo "${output}"
}


While this works when I just call sox-record, when I call a parent function like audio-postprocess, Ctrl-C doesn't do anything. (And I have to use pkill to kill rec.)
function audio-postprocess {
    local audio="$(sox-record)"

    # Process the audio file...
    echo "${audio}"
}



SIGINT doesn't propagate to parents. Upon ^C, the kernel sends the SIGINT to the foreground process group of the terminal.
When that zsh script is started in a terminal, your interactive shell will have created a process group (a job) for it, made it the foreground process group of the terminal and executed the script. All processes started by that script, including the subshells and the one executing rec will be in that group and will all receive SIGINT upon ^C.
If you want for only the process running rec to receive that signal, ignore SIGINT globally at the top level with trap '' INT, and restore it only for rec with (trap - INT; rec...).
function transcribe_audio {
    print -r Would transcribe $1
}
function sox-record {
    local output="${1-$(mktemp).wav}"
    (trap - INT; rec -- "$output" trim 0 300)
    print -r -- "$output"
}
function audio-postprocess {
    local audio="$(sox-record)"
    # Process the audio file...
    print -r -- "$audio"
}
function audio-transcribe {
    local audio="$(audio-postprocess)"
    transcribe_audio "$audio"
}
trap '' INT
audio-transcribe
trap - INT

# rest of the script not immune to SIGINT

You can also move the trap's inside audio-transcribe but you need to remember not to run it in a subshell, or then the ignoring of SIGINT will only apply to that subshell and its descendants, not the parent process.
...
function audio-transcribe {
    trap '' INT
    local audio="$(audio-postprocess)"
    transcribe_audio "$audio"
    trap - INT
}
audio-transcribe         # OK
(audio-transcribe)       # not OK
blah=$(audio-transcribe) # not OK
audio-transcribe | blah  # not OK

Having the script do job control itself, that is put rec in its own process group and make that process group the foreground process groups is an approach that could also work, but in zsh (5.9 at least), you can't do that with the monitor option (as set by set -m) alone as in non-interactive invocations, it creates process groups for commands, but doesn't change the terminal's foreground process group, so it would have the opposite effect to what you want.
For zsh to be willing to do terminal job control, you need interactive (-i) instead.
$ zsh -fc 'ps -o pid,pgid,tpgid,args; exit'
    PID    PGID   TPGID COMMAND
  32962   32962   32977 /bin/zsh
  32977   32977   32977 zsh -fc ps -o pid,pgid,tpgid,args; exit
  32978   32977   32977 ps -o pid,pgid,tpgid,args

Neither -i nor -m, ps in the same process group as the parent and in foreground.
$ zsh -m -fc 'ps -o pid,pgid,tpgid,args; exit'
    PID    PGID   TPGID COMMAND
  32962   32962   32987 /bin/zsh
  32987   32987   32987 zsh -m -fc ps -o pid,pgid,tpgid,args; exit
  32988   32988   32987 ps -o pid,pgid,tpgid,args

With -m alone, ps is in a new process group, but that's not been made the foreground process group of the terminal (tpgid), so it's actually in background so won't get the SIGINT upon ^C.
$ zsh -i -fc 'ps -o pid,pgid,tpgid,args; exit'
    PID    PGID   TPGID COMMAND
  32962   32962   32997 /bin/zsh
  32996   32996   32997 zsh -i -fc ps -o pid,pgid,tpgid,args; exit
  32997   32997   32997 ps -o pid,pgid,tpgid,args

With -i, which implies -m, ps is in a new process group which is in foreground this time, while zsh is itself in background.
Playing with job control in scripts is however generally a bad idea as it's source of all sorts of nasty unexpected behaviours, so I wouldn't go there. If you do, make sure your write it:
zsh -ifc 'rec -- "$1" trim 0 300' zsh "$output"

Do not embed the expansion of $output in the zsh code, as that would make it a command injection vulnerability.

I want to separate the usage of audio-transcribe from its internal implementation. It's inconvenient that I always have to remember to properly handle signals when using audio-transcribe. Are you suggesting that my ideal solution isn't possible to achieve? Thanks.

@HappyFace see edit.

Thanks. I guess I have to write my own audio recorder that stops when the user presses ENTER. BTW, I was properly quoting output using the (qq@) flags, I just simplified the code for the question. :D

I'm not sure I understand your actual concern, if a command (whether that's a shell script or other) must not die upon ^C, it has to take the necessary precaution such as blocking or ignoring SIGINT or put itself outside of the foreground process group of the terminal, there's no way around that.
